# How many ways are there to assign 5 tasks to 4 people

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Below I did a problem but I need someone to check this for me.

How many ways are there to assign $5$ tasks to $4$ people if there are no restrictions on the number of tasks (even none) that can be assigned to just one person.

So what is $4^5 = 1024$.

$4$ options each time for $5$ things, therefore $4\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 4 $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are the tasks distinct or identical ?

Comment: they are distinct tasks

Comment: Then why are you doubting your answer ?

Comment: Your solution is correct.